# How to determine for this question whether this set is a vector space or not?

Tags: vector-spaces

Hey I'm currently doing some revision and came across this question:
[Question Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COxkP.png)

I'm still learning how to insert more complex equations into stack exchange when asking questions hence I attached the question as an image so please bear with me.

I've actually attempted it & my solution is that:

**All sets are subsets of vector spaces. Hence, we first need to check on whether there are subspaces. (E,+,·) is a vector space because (0,0,0) belongs to E as 2(0)+3(0)=0, 0+2(0)=0 and 0+3(0)+5(0)=0 respectively. We also conclude that the zero element of the underlying vector space also in the subset.**

Although I feel that it's a bit too short for an answer. Can anyone help me on what more I can add or is this sufficient as the answer to the question already? Like do I need to do any workings or anything? Thanks a bunch guys.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $E$ is the kernel of the linear operator given by the matrix of coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote simply proves that $(0,0,0)\in E$. What about the rest? It remains to be proved that the sum of two elements of $E$ belongs to $E$ and that the product of an element of $E$ by a scalar belongs to $E$ too. This is easy, since $E$ is simply $\{(x,-2x,x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$.

Comment: Do you mean 3 elements of E?

Comment: No. I wrote what I meant.

Comment: I still don't get it, could you please elaborate like do you mean adding any 2 of the equations together?

Comment: *Where* do you think that I should have written about three elements of $E$ rather than two?

Comment: I still don't get it. How did you get E to be {(x,−2x,x)∣x∈R}?

Comment: I solved the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+2y+3z=0\\y+2z=0\\x+3y+5z=0\end{array}\right.$$The third equation is redundant, since it is the sum of the other two. You get from the second equation that $y=-2z$ and using this together with the first equation you get that $z=x$. So, the elements of $E$ are the triplets $(x,-2x,x)$, with $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Oh then if I add x with -2x then the answer should be the same as if I add -2x with x which proves the the commutativity for the internal composition law? Is that how it works?

Comment: No, it's not like that that it works at all. Now you note that if $x,y\in\Bbb R$, then$$(x,-2x,x)+(y,-2y,y)=(x+y,-2(x+y),x+y)\in E$$and therefore the sum of two elements of $E$ is again an element of $E$. And, if $\lambda\in\Bbb R$,$$\lambda(x,-2x,x)=(\lambda x,-2(\lambda x),\lambda x),$$and therefore if you multiply an element of $E$ by a scalar, then you get again an element of $E$.